# sql commit quickie

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

I have the transaction schedule above. The starting balances in Account 1 is 1000 and account 2 is 0.

if we were to read through these what are the account values of read uncommitted and read committed?

I get uncommitted 1) 1000 and 2) 0  and Committed 1) 2000 and 2) 2000

I trace through it for uncommitted as we do T1(top) T2(middle) T1(bottom) and since the bottom is a rollback its reverted to original state. Then with committed we run the same way but when we run T2(middle) the commit statement reads it to the DB and then the rollback does nothing?

Do I trace through this wrong?

Comment: Is it your homework for class?

Comment: Yes, and I've been watching videos but I can't seem to find the correct way to answer it. At least the answer I know is correct. I just want to make sure I'm understanding the concept correctly.

Comment: I think I understand it now. The T1 top part is run but because its not committed before the Select statement the value is not changed to 2000.